# Failed to compile CGMINER (BITCOIN) on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw32, bitcoin, mining

I'm trying to compile CGminer on my computer (Windows 7) using MinGW32.

Ive done all of the instructions that come with cgminer however I have got to a big problem. When following the instructions below i get the errors thrown underneath that.... any ideas?

```
adl.sh (optional - see below)
autoreconf -fvi
CFLAGS="-O2 -msse2" ./configure (additional config options, see below)
make
```

*Errors in mining shell*
sajadabdul@XKMS-060 ~
$ adl.sh
sh: adl.sh: command not found

sajadabdul@XKMS-060 ~
$ autoreconf -fvi
sh: autoreconf: command not found

Comment: Are you using CMD from windows?

Comment: @wesley.mesquita No, I am using MinGW Shell. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems some time ago, It seems that autoreconf command is missing.

I recommend you to install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), which has many complements to MIMGW (including autoreconf), and so you will be able to emulate the GNU env needed by your make.

Answer (score -2):

You need to type in this line in MinGW MSYS shell.

```
mount c:/mingw /mingw
```

only after that you can access the commands.